# Zend Framework Default Value Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hi i'm using zend framework to do my application
what i want to do is set a default value to an Zend_form_element_text

What i want is that when i start the .phtm page there is already a visible default value into a text area. A user can keep that value or change that.

I try to do $name->setValue but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use form setDefaults

```
$form->setDefaults(array('name' => 'some value'));
```

Comment: Thanks...like you write it doesn't work for me but $form->setDefault('nome', $obj->nome); it works!